# Is There A Better Way To Force Scrollbar Values To Certain Increments & Bind Values To A Textbox (C#)?

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I have a setting in my application that requires any value between 24 and 65520 that must be evenly divisible by 24.  I decided to implement this with a horizontal scrollbar and a textbox that shows the current value of the scrollbar, and can have a value manually typed into it (which then sets the scrollbar value).  The scrollbar has minimum = 24, maximum = 65520, small & large increments = 1. The default value at app launch is 960.  I ended up having to use a couple of event handlers for both the textbox and the scrollbar, and even still it didn't work perfectly.  My first mostly-working attempt was this:

```
    private void hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        int NewValue = e.NewValue;

        if (e.Type != ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            if (e.NewValue < e.OldValue)
            {
                NewValue = e.NewValue - (e.NewValue % 24);
            }
            else if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue)
            {
                NewValue = e.NewValue + (e.NewValue % 24 == 0 ? 0 : 24 - (e.NewValue % 24));
            }

            txtTicksPerQuarter.Text = NewValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value = NewValue;
        }
    }

    private void hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value.ToString() != txtTicksPerQuarter.Text)
        {
            hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicksPerQuarter.Text);
        }
    }

    private void txtTicksPerQuarter_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TrySetTicksPerQuarter();
    }

    private void txtTicksPerQuarter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            TrySetTicksPerQuarter();
    }

    private void TrySetTicksPerQuarter()
    {
        bool useOldValue = false;
        int TicksPerQuarter_OldValue = hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value;
        int TicksPerQuarter = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtTicksPerQuarter.Text, out TicksPerQuarter))
        {
            if (TicksPerQuarter % 24 == 0)
            {
                hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value = TicksPerQuarter;
            }
            else
            {
                useOldValue = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Must enter a value that is a multiple of 24, with a minimum of 24 and a maximum of 65520.", "Invalid TicksPerQuarter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            useOldValue = true;
        }

        if (useOldValue)
            txtTicksPerQuarter.Text = TicksPerQuarter_OldValue.ToString();
    }
```

This works fairly well, if I enter a value in the textbox and leave the box or press Enter, it will update the scrollbar accordingly, and if the value is not a proper multiple of 24 it will just reset itself to the last valid value and display a message to the user indicating the issue.  Scrolling the scrollbar updates the textbox in real time as you scroll, and everything basically works.  The problem is that when you click and drag the scrollbar, the moment you let results in a jump in the value (usually of a couple hundred or so, in either direction).  Not sure why it was happening, I started experimenting with changes the "Scroll" event on the scrollbar to see if I could fix it, so releasing the scrollbar after dragging it would result in the value staying what it displayed at the time you release it.  It took a lot of experimentation, including some drastic overhauls to everything that didn't even work as well as the code I put above, but ultimately the best I could get was to keep all the code above the same in the other events, and just change the Scroll event to this:

```
    ScrollEventType[] IncrementScrollEvents = new ScrollEventType[] { ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement, ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement, ScrollEventType.Last };
    ScrollEventType[] DecrementScrollEvents = new ScrollEventType[] { ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement, ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement, ScrollEventType.First };
    private void hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        int NewValue = e.NewValue;

        if (IncrementScrollEvents.Contains(e.Type))
        {
            NewValue = e.NewValue + (e.NewValue % 24 == 0 ? 0 : 24 - (e.NewValue % 24));
        }
        else if (DecrementScrollEvents.Contains(e.Type))
        {
            NewValue = e.NewValue - (e.NewValue % 24);
        }
        else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack)
        {
            if (e.NewValue < e.OldValue)
            {
                NewValue = e.NewValue - (e.NewValue % 24);
            }
            else if (e.NewValue > e.OldValue)
            {
                NewValue = e.NewValue + (e.NewValue % 24 == 0 ? 0 : 24 - (e.NewValue % 24));
            }
        }
        else if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value = NewValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        txtTicksPerQuarter.Text = NewValue.ToString();
    }
```

This definitely works better, and if I had to estimate it, I'd say maybe 4 out of 5 times you release the scrollbar, the value remains where it was at the last moment before you let go of the mouse button.  But it still isn't perfect.

I was hoping there is a better way to do this, both in terms of functionality being just that little bit more perfect than it is now, and perhaps even in terms of the overall complexity of the code.  I didn't expect to have to write code in 4 different events across 2 controls to do this, but perhaps there isn't a better way after all?

EDIT 1:

I had an idea to use increments of 1 and min/max 1-2730 instead of 24-65520 and then instead of doing math and verification and manually setting the value of the scrollbar to ensure it's a multiple of 24, I will instead just multiply its real value by 24 to get the usable value and the display value for the textbox.  This code is now identical in functionality to what I had above, with a lot less complexity.  I also moved the warning messagebox for invalid entry in the textbox so that it displays a message even when the user types something that can't even be converted to an integer:

```
    private void hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTicksPerQuarter.Text = (e.NewValue * 24).ToString();
    }

    private void txtTicksPerQuarter_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TrySetTicksPerQuarter();
    }

    private void txtTicksPerQuarter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            TrySetTicksPerQuarter();
    }

    private void TrySetTicksPerQuarter()
    {
        bool useOldValue = false;
        int TicksPerQuarter_OldValue = hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value;
        int TicksPerQuarter = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtTicksPerQuarter.Text, out TicksPerQuarter))
        {
            if (TicksPerQuarter % 24 == 0)
            {
                hScrollBar_TicksPerQuarter.Value = (TicksPerQuarter / 24);
            }
            else
            {
                useOldValue = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            useOldValue = true;
        }

        if (useOldValue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must enter a value that is a multiple of 24, with a minimum of 24 and a maximum of 65520.", "Invalid TicksPerQuarter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtTicksPerQuarter.Text = (TicksPerQuarter_OldValue * 24).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The scrollbar still jumps occasionally when you let go of the mouse button when you're dragging it left and right.   I still don't have a solution for that particular problem, unless it's really not something that I can fix due to the way the mouse and scroll bar play with each other?

Comment: It occurs to me now (not sure why it took me so long!) that maybe I should just have the scrollbar's min & max values = 1 & 2730, and have the actual value of the scrollbar simply be in increments of 1, eliminating a lot of the complexity of ensuring it's in increments of 24 ... and then just simply multiply the value of the scrollbar by 24 when I use it and when I set the display in the textbox.  So the user only perceives it as being 24 - 65520 with increments of 24, even though the scrollbar itself holds values between 1 - 2730 in increments of 1.  This probably makes a lot more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a small WinForms demo app using just a single scrollbar (hScrollbar1) and a label (Label1).

Created the form's Load event handler and added the following code:

```
hScrollBar1.Minimum = 1;
hScrollBar1.Maximum = 65520 / 24;
hScrollBar1.Value = 960 / 24;
hScrollBar1.LargeChange = 1;
```

Created hScrollBar1's ValueChanged event handler and added the following code:

```
label1.Text = (hScrollBar1.Value * 24).ToString();
```

Seems to work fine for me this way. Not sure if I could get it to work when using stepping values of 24 in the scrollbar property settings... Sorry for that...

Edit: Just saw your own comment. I agree. :)